# Error serializing rows of data to the psql command

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, bulkloader, pdi

I have a job where I am using only 2 things, Table input and pgbulkloader as output.
While running the job its constantly throwing error as **Error serializing rows of data to the psql command**
Any suggestions??

Error message :

```
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 - **Error serializing rows of data to the psql command**
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 - **Stream closed**
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pgbulkloader.PGBulkLoader.writeRowToPostgres(PGBulkLoader.java:450)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pgbulkloader.PGBulkLoader.processRow(PGBulkLoader.java:316)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:60)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 - Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pgbulkloader.PGBulkLoader.writeRowToPostgres(PGBulkLoader.java:361)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 -     ... 3 more
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - PGBulkLdr_PendingSoftware.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=14, R=15, W=14, U=0, E=1)2015/09/09 17:00:54 - T_2050_Software_Pending - ERROR (version 5.0.7, build 1 from 2014-05-30_20-16-36 by buildguy) : Errors detected!

2015/09/09 17:00:54 - Src_PendingSoftwareRequests_Tbl.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - T_2050_Software_Pending - T_2050_Software_Pending
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - T_2050_Software_Pending - T_2050_Software_Pending
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - Src_PendingSoftwareRequests_Tbl.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.7, build 1 from 2014-05-30_20-16-36 by buildguy) : Unexpected error closing query : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - Src_PendingSoftwareRequests_Tbl.0 - **Couldn't close query: resultset or prepared statements**
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - Src_PendingSoftwareRequests_Tbl.0 - **Cancel has been invoked on this Statement.**
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - Src_PendingSoftwareRequests_Tbl.0 - Finished processing (I=121, O=0, R=0, W=119, U=0, E=1)
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - T_2050_Software_Pending - T_2050_Software_Pending
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - T_2050_Software_Pending - ERROR (version 5.0.7, build 1 from 2014-05-30_20-16-36 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - T_2050_Software_Pending - T_2050_Software_Pending
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - J_2050_Batch_Pending_Staging - Finished job entry [T_2050_Software_Pending] (result=[false])
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - J_2050_Batch_Pending_Staging - Job execution finished
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - Kitchen - Finished!
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - Kitchen - ERROR (version 5.0.7, build 1 from 2014-05-30_20-16-36 by buildguy) : Finished with errors
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - Kitchen - Start=2015/09/09 17:00:28.851, Stop=2015/09/09 17:00:54.424
2015/09/09 17:00:54 - Kitchen - Processing ended after 25 seconds.
```

Comment: Show your work. Without any more information, people won't be able to figure out what's wrong. See: [ask]

Comment: Hi,
its not allowing me to upload image.
I have pasted the error message there in my question.

Comment: Text is better anyway, so thanks. Check the PostgreSQL server error log, it looks like a sudden connection drop maybe. Hard to say for sure, since I'm not sure quite what this software is or what it's talking to at the low level.

Comment: Did you try reducing the rows taken in to ktr via table input?

Comment: Can you share the ktr/job files?

Comment: I have never had much luck with the PG bulk loader. It still seems to be "experimental". I haven't used it in a while, but I always found myself just using `Table Output` or writing a text file and using the COPY command from `psql` to load it.